# Ugly differentiation questions

Tags: calculus, probability, derivatives

The CDF of a Weibull random variable X is given by
$$F(x)=1−\exp[-(\lambda x)^{\beta}],\, x>0$$
Find the PDF of X

---

Now, I understand the procedures that need to be taken to do this type of question, however, I can't even start the question.
I know that in order to find the PDF of X, I must differentiate F(X), but I can't even do that!

Can someone please help me by showing me how one would differentiate an ugly function like this?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}[e^{f(x)}] = f'(x)\cdot e^{f(x)}$. Your $f(x) = -(\lambda x)^\beta$; can you differentiate $f(x)$?

Comment: I thinkthere is something wrong with the formatting - should the $\beta$ be inside the brackets - $\exp\left[-(\lambda x)^{\beta}\right]$?

Comment: @danielson you really cleared this up for me. I DON'T KNOW WHY I DON'T SEE THIS BASIC STUFF FROM THE VERY BEGINNING!

Comment: No reason to shout. @Shotokan

Comment: Hahaha @ThomasAndrews, I just get frustrated at my stupidity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain rule and power rule.
Take it step by step and you will find it super easy.